# Struggling to make gRPC-web and HTTPS work

Tags: grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I've got a SPA web app that uses gRPC web and envoy to proxy back to a server that speaks gRPC.  This all works great, no problems.

I'm trying to make this secure using HTTPS/TLS and just keep running into issues and can't make it work.

Our setup is this:

```
Web Client SPA app (accessed from web node.js server also running on the lahinch server.  URL is https://lahinch.mycorp.com ).  Web app connects to the envoy proxy using this address "https://coxos.mycorp.COM:8090"
      
        \
      
    Envoy Proxy  (coxos - 172.16.0.116) - listens on port 8090 and proxies to port 50251
            \
              \
                Backend gRPC server  (lahinch - 172.16.0.109) - listens on port 50251
```

From reading the envoy docs, the web client is downstream and the backend server is upstream.

Here is my envoy.yaml file

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8090
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                '@type': >-
                  type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                    typed_config:
                      '@type': >-
                        type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                      path: /dev/stdout
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.http_grpc
                    typed_config:
                      '@type': >-
                        type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.grpc.v3.HttpGrpcAccessLogConfig
                      common_config:
                        log_name: envoygrpclog
                        grpc_service:
                          envoy_grpc:
                            cluster_name: controlweb_backendservice
                        transport_api_version: V3
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains:
                        - '*'
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: /
                          route:
                            cluster: controlweb_backendservice
                            hash_policy:
                              - header:
                                  header_name: x-session-hash
                            max_stream_duration:
                              grpc_timeout_header_max: 300s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - safe_regex:
                              google_re2: {}
                              regex: .*
                        allow_methods: 'GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS'
                        allow_headers: >-
                          keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,grpc-status-details-bin,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout,access-token,x-session-hash
                        expose_headers: >-
                          grpc-status-details-bin,grpc-status,grpc-message,access-token
                        max_age: '1728000'
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                    typed_config:
                      '@type': >-
                        type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                    typed_config:
                      '@type': >-
                        type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      '@type': >-
                        type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.17.0/api-v3/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3/tls.proto#extensions-transport-sockets-tls-v3-downstreamtlscontext
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                tls_certificates:
                  - certificate_chain:
                      # Certificate must be PEM-encoded
                      filename: /etc/lahinch.pem
                    private_key:
                      filename: /etc/lahinch.key.pem
                validation_context:
                   trusted_ca:
                      filename: /etc/ssl/certs/ZZZ-CA256.pem
  clusters:
    - name: controlweb_backendservice
      type: LOGICAL_DNS
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_controlweb_backendservice
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: lahinch.mycorp.com
                      port_value: 50251
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          '@type': >-
            type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
              - certificate_chain:
                  filename: /etc/lahinch.pem
                private_key:
                  filename: /etc/lahinch.key.pem
            validation_context:
              trusted_ca:
                filename: /etc/ssl/certs/ZZZ-CA256.pem
```

Using this, I'm getting the following in the envoy log when I try and run my web app:

```
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.939][17][debug][conn_handler] [source/server/connection_handler_impl.cc:501] [C2] new connection
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.945][17][debug][http] [source/common/http/conn_manager_impl.cc:254] [C2] new stream
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.945][17][debug][http] [source/common/http/conn_manager_impl.cc:886] [C2][S3055347406573314092] request headers complete (end_stream=false):
':authority', 'coxos.mycorp.com:8090'
':path', '/WanderAuth.HostService/LogIn'
':method', 'POST'
'connection', 'keep-alive'
'content-length', '124'
'accept', 'application/grpc-web-text'
'x-user-agent', 'grpc-web-javascript/0.1'
'access-token', ''
'x-grpc-web', '1'
'user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.68'
'grpc-timeout', '90000m'
'content-type', 'application/grpc-web-text'
'origin', 'https://lahinch.mycorp.com'
'sec-fetch-site', 'same-site'
'sec-fetch-mode', 'cors'
'sec-fetch-dest', 'empty'
'referer', 'https://lahinch.mycorp.com/'
'accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br'
'accept-language', 'en-US,en;q=0.9'

[2021-04-09 22:08:33.946][17][debug][router] [source/common/router/router.cc:425] [C2][S3055347406573314092] cluster 'controlweb_backendservice' match for URL '/WanderAuth.HostService/LogIn'
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.946][17][debug][router] [source/common/router/router.cc:582] [C2][S3055347406573314092] router decoding headers:
':authority', 'coxos.mycorp.com:8090'
':path', '/WanderAuth.HostService/LogIn'
':method', 'POST'
':scheme', 'https'
'accept', 'application/grpc-web-text'
'x-user-agent', 'grpc-web-javascript/0.1'
'access-token', ''
'x-grpc-web', '1'
'user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.68'
'grpc-timeout', '90000m'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'origin', 'https://lahinch.mycorp.com'
'sec-fetch-site', 'same-site'
'sec-fetch-mode', 'cors'
'sec-fetch-dest', 'empty'
'referer', 'https://lahinch.mycorp.com/'
'accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br'
'accept-language', 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-request-id', 'a4a041ab-dc29-4ed7-a342-90ac03b3be3c'
'te', 'trailers'
'grpc-accept-encoding', 'identity'
'x-envoy-expected-rq-timeout-ms', '15000'

[2021-04-09 22:08:33.946][17][debug][pool] [source/common/http/conn_pool_base.cc:79] queueing stream due to no available connections
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.946][17][debug][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:106] creating a new connection
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.946][17][debug][client] [source/common/http/codec_client.cc:41] [C3] connecting
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.946][17][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:860] [C3] connecting to 172.16.0.109:50251
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.946][17][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:876] [C3] connection in progress
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.946][17][debug][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:1184] [C3] updating connection-level initial window size to 268435456
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.946][17][debug][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:755] [C2][S3055347406573314092] request end stream
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.947][17][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:666] [C3] connected
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.947][17][debug][connection] [source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:224] [C3] TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.948][17][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:241] [C3] closing socket: 0
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.948][17][debug][connection] [source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:224] [C3] TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.948][17][debug][client] [source/common/http/codec_client.cc:99] [C3] disconnect. resetting 0 pending requests
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.948][17][debug][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:343] [C3] client disconnected, failure reason: TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.948][17][debug][router] [source/common/router/router.cc:1026] [C2][S3055347406573314092] upstream reset: reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.948][17][debug][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:839] [C2][S3055347406573314092] Sending local reply with details upstream_reset_before_response_started{connection failure,TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER}
[2021-04-09 22:08:33.948][17][debug][http] [source/common/http/conn_manager_impl.cc:1484] [C2][S3055347406573314092] encoding headers via codec (end_stream=false):
':status', '503'
'content-length', '190'
'content-type', 'application/grpc-web-text+proto'
'access-control-allow-origin', 'https://lahinch.mycorp.com'
'access-control-expose-headers', 'grpc-status-details-bin,grpc-status,grpc-message,access-token'
'date', 'Fri, 09 Apr 2021 22:08:33 GMT'
'server', 'envoy'

[2021-04-09 22:08:36.139][9][debug][upstream] [source/common/upstream/logical_dns_cluster.cc:101] starting async DNS resolution for lahinch.mycorp.com
[2021-04-09 22:08:36.139][9][debug][main] [source/server/server.cc:199] flushing stats
[2021-04-09 22:08:36.141][9][debug][upstream] [source/common/upstream/logical_dns_cluster.cc:109] async DNS resolution complete for lahinch.mycorp.com
[2021-04-09 22:08:36.141][9][debug][upstream] [source/common/upstream/logical_dns_cluster.cc:155] DNS refresh rate reset for lahinch.mycorp.com, refresh rate 5000 ms
```

So the error appears to be this: TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

I've looked up this error and it appears to be be related to security and certificates.  But I haven't been able to find a good answer as to what I'm doing wrong.

When it comes to the required certs, should the certs be the same that is used by client(downstream), the proxy or the backend(upstream server) or both? I've tried using different certs for the different servers and the same certs for the servers and I still get the same error.

Comment: There is an example of using grpc-web with TLS here: https://github.com/salrashid123/grpc_web_with_gke. There's a section on how to use certs. You do not have to use GKE if you don't need to.